# How to avoid spaces other than paragraph while using parskip package?

Tags: table-of-contents, paragraphs, parskip

When I did not use **parskip package** table of content seems compact but when I used parskip package I see some other contents i.e. itemized items, table of content, enums etc. also getting spaces between items. But my intention is to only apply space inside paragraphes only.**How can I use **parskip** which will affect only to the paragraph but not other items?**

Using below code,

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{parskip}

\title{\normalfont{Technical Report: Loren Ipsum}} 

\author{{Alex Murphy}}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction} 
\subsection{Subsec1} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames

\subsection{Subsec1} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

\end{document}
```

Output is like,

[image]

Although space is not shown in MWE but in my large thesis book I find extra space between items of table of content as I mentioned in red text in the figure.

Comment: the parskip package resets a few of the lengths but technically almost everything is a paragraph so you need to reset most other lengths to do a complete job. eg enumitem package will let you customise list lengths.  (unrelated but there should not be font commands in `\title` or duplicated `{{` in `\author`.

Answer (score 1):

With KOMA-Script the `parskip`-package isn't necessary. See pages 78/79 of the documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

Are you really sure, you want to use an article class for a book? Wouldn't `scrbook` be more suitable for such a task?

Be that as it may, you can and should do something like this (`parskip=full*`):

```latex
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    parskip=full*,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\normalfont{Technical Report: Loren Ipsum}}

\author{{Alex Murphy}}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsec1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames

\subsection{Subsec1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image: KOMA-Script parskip]